# Scala Lift - Get server root (disk)

Tags: scala, lift, root

I need to find out the root for the server that my Lift app is running on as I make use of imagemagick and openoffice to convert files into images.

I can get this working on my windows dev machine by simply hard coding C:/ before the path to the file, but on our Linux server using:

```
/[app name goes here]
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `java.io.File.listRoots`, followed by some code to select the root you wish to use.

Also, `/appName` is extremely unlikely to work, since apps are not placed at root.  Type `which oowriter` for example to get the path to `oowriter` (Open Office / LibreOffice Writer).  Many applications are at `/usr/bin`; some are at `/bin`; others may be elsewhere.